# I have a numpy 2 dimensional complex number data, how to use this array to do 2D-FFT and plot the result

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, plot, complex-numbers

I have a 48x64 size numpy array of complex number.
How can I do 2D-FFT with this array? After I get the result, it returns another same size array of complex number, how can I plot it?
Here is what I have done.

```
a = np.fft.fft2(data_total_dataframe)
```

data_total_dataframe is my original 48x64 complex number array.
So after this code, I will have the numpy array a.
Is there any method to plot this array so that I can see any type of graph?
I'm new to python and FFT processing.
Thank you in advance for the help